# How to compare two pairs from one table to two pairs from another table on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, unpivot

I want to compare both values from the following tables.

Arlarp

```
+------+--------+
|ARLID | ARPID  |
+------+--------+
|  AA  | AIA    |
|  OA  | AIA    |
|  AA  | ATL    |
|  AA  | DFW    |
|  AA  | LAX    |
|  DL  | ORD    |
|  EK  | ORD    |
|  AC  | YYZ    |
+------+--------+
```

Flight

```
+------+---------+----------+
| ARLID| ARPID_1 | ARPID_2  |
+------+---------+----------+
|  AA  |   ATL   |   DFW    |
|  AA  |   DFW   |   ATL    |
|  UA  |   ORD   |   DFW    |
+------+---------+----------+
```

From Arlarp, we have existing pairs of values.  I want to find the missing pairs of values of Arlarp from Flight that don't exist in Flight when comparing flight's ARLID with ARPID_1 and ARPID_2.

This is what the result should be:

```
+------+---------+
| ARLID| ARPID   |
+------+---------+
| UA   |  ORD    |
+------+---------+
| UA   |  DFA    |
+------+---------+
```

Comment: From result, I meant to type DFW instead of DFA

Answer (score 0):

One option is to unpivot the `flight` table with `union all`, and then pull out rows that do not exist in `alarp` with `not exists`:

```
select f.*
from (
    select arlid, arpid_1 arpid from flight
    union all select arlid, arpid_2 from flight
) f
where not exists (select 1 from alarp a where a.arlid = f.arlid and a.arpid = f.arpd)
```